# Hide h:outputText element if there was no user input

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

```
<h:form id="aform">

    <p:growl id="debug-growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />

    <p:inputText id="expression" value="#{debug.expression}" required ="true" />

    <p:commandButton update="debug-growl" value="Process" action="#{debug.myaction}" />

    <h:outputText value="Source regular expression: #{debug.expression}" rendered="#{not empty debug.expression}" />

</h:form>
```

the bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Debug implements Serializable {

    private String expression; //getter & setter is present
```

When I enter the value it then shows after submit in the `h:outputText` element.
But if I enter empty value (which is wrong) then in the `h:outputText` element still present the previous value.

How can I hide the 'h:outputText' when no values was submitted?

Comment: Try changing your @ViewScoped annotation

Comment: @JokerTheFourth: To what and why?

Comment: To hide something you can use `Disabled` or `Rendred` in this case (Rendred) it will be invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I see 2 issues with the above code.

1. Your not updating the h:outputText on the commandButton click. You need to add an ID to the h:outputText and add it as an update to the command button

   ```
   <p:commandButton update="debug-growl someText" value="Process" action="#{debug.myaction}" />

   <h:outputText id = "someText" value="Source regular expression: #{debug.expression}" rendered="#{not empty debug.expression}" />
   ```
2. The required ="true" on the inputText is not allowing the empty value to be submitted to the server. Thus the h:outputText will never be empty, therfore this value will always be rendered. To fix this, I would do my validation on the server.

   JSF

   Remove the required="true" tag

   ```
   <p:inputText id="expression" value="#{debug.expression}"/>
   ```

   Java

   ```
   public void myAction(){

       //check to make sure inputText isnt null/blank first
       if(StringUtils.isBlank(expression))
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error", "Must provide value"));
       else{
            //business logic
       }
   }
   ```